# Conditional select from postgresql DB error

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I used postgresql DB.
This order is working.

```
# select * from test where id=3299;
   id   |  m_id  | old_code  | new_code  |          log_date
--------+--------+-----------+-----------+----------------------------
  3299  | 603990 | 220088242 | 234024141 | 2018-08-09 18:40:05.655615
(1 row)
```

but, other condition's this order is not working.

```
# select * from test where old_code = "220088242";
ERROR:  column "220088242" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from test where old_code = "220088242";
```

this is DB's detail.

```
# \d test;
                                   Table "test"
  Column  |            Type             |                          Modifiers

-----------------
 id       | integer                     | not null default nextval('test_id
_seq'::regclass)
 m_id     | integer                     |
 old_code | character varying(12)       |
 new_code | character varying(12)       |
 log_date | timestamp without time zone |
Indexes:
"l_shina_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

what is problem?

Comment: Double quotes are for delimited identifiers, e.g. a column named 220088242 (very strange name...) Use single quotes for string literals, and no quotes at all for numeric literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in postgresql
" " could be used to refer to a column or table named "select"

A string constant in SQL is an arbitrary sequence of characters bounded by single quotes ('), for example 'This is a string'.so  this is not the same as a double-quote character (")

As a result you have to use single quote like below

```
select * from test where old_code = '220088242'
```

Answer (score 0):

use like clause

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE old_code LIKE '220088242';
```